# How can I attach one router link and one dialog box in dropdown in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-router

[image]I have to get a dropdown menu and attach the router link to other component and one dialog component for dialog box in it.

```
<td align="center">
    <v-btn round class="mx-2 dropdown-menu" fab small v-bind:style="displayClass(key[2])" v-bind:key="key[1]"
        v-for="(key) in props.item[6]">
        <div>

        <!--option 1-->
        <router-link :to="{ name : 'modifyinfo', params:{prip : key[0], Name : props.item[1], pripId : key[1]}}"> {{displaycase(key[0])}}
        </router-link>
        <!--option 2-->
        <dialog :prip_name=props.item[1] :prip_info=key[0]>{{displaycase(key[0])}}</dialog>

        </div>

    </v-btn>
</td>
```

I need to get the router link and dialog as option in dropdown in the div. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. You want to render the router-link and dialog component when the user hovers on the buttons? or click?

Comment: Thanks for answer, on click I want to render it on click. Basically I need a dropdown on that button and then they should bring me those two option, first to route and second to the dialog box. {{displaycase(key[0])}} we can move to the button. Currently I have to comment the router to check the dialog box and vice versa. Hope I am able to explain.